proc_get_parent_data() Linux Kernel
Please explain to me what this feature is, and has it been removed in the 5.10 kernel?
I'm trying to build a kernel module and the compiler tells me that this function is not defined, where do I get something like this or help me figure out what it is?
I have no idea how to fix it.
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- -C /lib/modules/5.10.198-android12-9/build M=/root/Desktop/123/rtl8188eus  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/Desktop/a24/out/target/product/a24/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/kernel-5.10'
CC [M]  /root/Desktop/123/rtl8188eus/os_dep/linux/rtw_proc.o
AR [M]  /root/Desktop/123/rtl8188eus/8188eu.o

+ [ -n  ]
+ echo -n -g0683c3382f7a-dirty
+ set +x
  LTO [M] /root/Desktop/123/rtl8188eus/8188eu.lto.o
  MODPOST /root/Desktop/123/rtl8188eus/Module.symvers
  ERROR: modpost: "proc_get_parent_data" [/root/Desktop/123/rtl8188eus/8188eu.ko] undefined!
  ERROR: modpost: "kernel_read" [/root/Desktop/123/rtl8188eus/8188eu.ko] undefined!
  make[3]: *** [/root/Desktop/a24/kernel-5.10/scripts/Makefile.modpost:168: /root/Desktop/123/rtl8188eus/Module.symvers] Error 1
  make[3]: *** Deleting file '/root/Desktop/123/rtl8188eus/Module.symvers'
  make[2]: *** [/root/Desktop/a24/kernel-5.10/Makefile:1851: modules] Error 2
  make[1]: *** [/root/Desktop/a24/kernel-5.10/Makefile:192: __sub-make] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/Desktop/a24/out/target/product/a24/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/kernel-5.10'


In kernel 5.10 the proc_get_parent_data function is exported as GPL only. Your module likely isn't GPL, so can't access this.
